# Take control of interpreter in multithreaded program

Tags: python

In python interpreter mode, i launched a thread that points to function that prints statements in an infinite loop. Now i would like to take control of the interpreter again to launch another thread. How can i take get back to the interperter >>?

Comment: interpreter is there. But it is hidden by the prints.

Comment: I can't seem to take control and execute commands when my first thread prints!

Comment: try to redirect output insteat to send it to console.

Comment: Code is ready in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's supose that this is your code  ([from http://mundogeek.net/ ¿QUÉ SON LOS PROCESOS Y LOS THREADS?](http://mundogeek.net/archivos/2008/04/18/threads-en-python/)):

```
import threading  

class MiThread(threading.Thread):  
      def __init__(self, num):  
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
          self.num = num  

      def run(self):  
          while true:
             print "Soy el hilo", self.num  

print "Soy el hilo principal"  

for i in range(0, 10):  
    t = MiThread(i)  
    t.start()
```

Then, insteat to sent print to console, you can redirect output to a file:

```
      def run(self):  
          f = open('/tmp/workfile{0}.txt'.format(self.num), 'r+')
          while true:
             f.write("Soy el hilo {0}\n".format( self.num ))
```

or you can create a thread method/property that return your own thread status information:

```
class MiThread(threading.Thread):  
      def __init__(self, num):  
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
          self.num = num  
          self.status = ''

      def run(self):  
          while true:
             self.status = "Soy el hilo {0}".format( self.num )


t1 = MiThread(i)  
t1.start()  
t2 = MiThread(i)  #<-- at this point you get back interpreter
t2.start()  
print t1.status
```